# How to login in Heroku after lost MFA app in mobile

Tags: heroku, multi-factor-authentication

I can not able to add new MFA app in aacount and I lost my mobile where I was install 2FAS authentication app.
I have created ticket in heroku but I still didn't get any response from them.

I have username and password but without MFA code I cannot able to login.

Please help me if any one know.

Comment: same issue here, I have contacted support, heard back once, advised on commits hashs and app names to verify myself, but never heard back after that. I Will keep you posted if they help

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't directly a programming question (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions)